# New Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I am beginner in Android. So I need some help. I have made a new Activity in Android that works but when I typed something in other activity that doesn't show up. I am unable to figure out why it is not working as expected. According to me it should show "New Activity Launched" in a new activity.

Source code MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AditionalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

AditionalActivity.class

```
package com.example.bablu.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by Bablu on 6/3/2016.
 */
public class AditionalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState) ;
        setContentView(R.layout.additional_activity);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.bablu.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

aditional_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Activity Launched"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:textSize="32sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you registered in manifest your AditionalActivity ?

Comment: any error occurs in your code.?

Comment: Yes I registered in the manifest file. And no error occurred!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AditionalActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

@ your **OnClickListener**